# How to explode data from JSON in SUPER data type?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

I have to explode data from JSON in date type SUPER.

The reason why I created data type in SUPER becuase the size of data is too large to put in VARCHAR. I tried to use JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT and JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT to explode data but it keep returns error

`ERROR: function json_extract_array_element_text(super, integer) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types.`

There are a lots of array nested inside and they're required to be in the report.

The stucture of the object is

```
    {
        "id": "",
        "productModelId": "",
        "name": {
            "en": "",
            "th": ""
        },
        "status": "COMPLETE",
        "itemStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "qty": 1,
        "pricePerUnit": 135,
        "discountPerUnit": 0,
        "totalDiscount": 0,
        "totalPrice": 135,
        "vatTotal": 8.83,
        "imageUrls": [
            ""
        ],
        "subItems": [
            {
                "sku": "",
                "name": {
                    "en": "-",
                    "th": "-"
                },
                "barcode": "",
                "qty": 1,
                "pricePerUnit": 135,
                "discountPerUnit": 0,
                "totalDiscount": 0,
                "vatRate": 7,
                "vatPerUnit": 8.83,
                "cost": 120,
                "vatTotal": 8.83,
                "priceExcludeVat": 126.17,
                "totalPrice": 135,
                "bundleType": "DEFAULT",
                "unitName": "",
                "object_id": {
                    "oid": ""
                }
            }
        ],
        "note": "",
        "createdDate": {
            "date": "2023-06-14T07:44:55.000Z"
        },
        "lastModifiedDate": {
            "date": "2023-06-14T07:44:55.000Z"
        },
        "object_id": {
            "oid": "64896ff90c3adc715e33d3df"
        }
    }
```

Any ideas to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The function `json_extract_array_element_text` only takes the argument  JSON as string type. But you are providing here `super` type instead of `string` type. Reference [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT.html)

You need to serialize that supertype first. The query could be like this one.

```
json_extract_array_element_text(JSON_SERIALIZE(super), integer)
```

Please also check this documentation for [JSON_SERILAIZE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_SERIALIZE.html)